# What if the bomb bay is hit?

Tags: wwii, bomber, ordnance

The bomb bay on s heavy bomber is a somewhat big target. If the ordnance were to explode, it would be very dangerous for nearby aircraft. But I haven't really seen much evidence of concern over this during the massed air raids in WWII, Korea, or Vietnam. What am I missing?

Comment: No heavy bomber air crew was ever known to register a complaint about the sensitivity of their ordinance to enemy fire.

Comment: Are you asking about the situation where flak or enemy aircraft rounds penetrate the bomb bay doors and strike a bomb? I would imagine (but my search-fu isn't helping me confirm) that the bombs weren't actually armed until they fell out of their bomb racks, therefore they wouldn't be terribly likely to explode within the aircraft.

Comment: I definitely have read stories of WW2 bombers exploding into nothingness because the entire bomb load detonated under enemy fire.  But I don't think it would be practical or even useful to try to armor the bomb bay against a direct hit from a large-caliber AA shell.  With that kind of a direct hit the airplane's going down regardless of whether the bombs explode or not.  Is there some smaller shell caliber against which it would make sense to try to provide armored protection for the bomb bay?  Hmm, dunno--

Comment: Reminds me of the story of plane reinforcements being designed on the basis of damage seen when they came back from battle.  The problem being that the places needing reinforcement were on the planes that *didn't* come back.

Comment: Major Kong will just have to go down to the bomb bay and fix the problem   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is5u5uhyc6s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Modern explosives are remarkably unwilling to go off without the correct primer. Some of them will not explode even when set on fire (and just burn in that case).

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/78764/31425

---

> High explosive is relatively less sensitive and requires a primer's blast wave or high-speed impact from a metallic object (speed ≥ **1000 m/s**) to detonate.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-19-2856-7_2

The muzzle velocity of the ["88" antiaircraft gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.8_cm_Flak_18/36/37/41), which was common enough to be the origin of the word flak, was only 840 m/s.
Its shell was about [9 kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.8_cm_KwK_36), thus with a kinetic energy of about 3.2 MJ.  Even at a fairly low cruising altitude for a bomber of 15000 ft or 4500 m, the shell would have converted about 0.4 MJ of that to potential energy, leaving it with a speed of about **790 m/s**.

Although a high caliber bullet from an airborne attacker might reach 1000 m/s, it will have slowed down after penetrating everything between the airplane's skin and the 'meat' of a bomb.

---

**Edit**, from comments:

BF 110's, when attacking bombers from below with ammunition (often just 30 mm, and not big AA shells) [could](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%A4ge_Musik#Operational_use) detonate bombs.  I don't have authoritative confirmation of such detonations, but Wikipedia says that

> The optimum target for the night fighter was the wing fuel tanks, not the fuselage or bomb bay, because of the risk that exploding bombs would damage the attacker.

So, at least for aerial attackers, the reason that bombs still on board were rarely reported to have been exploded is that the attackers deliberately avoided that.

Comment: Weren't the AA shells fired by the 88 explosive?  After the shell explodes, some of its pieces could be going pretty fast.

Comment: @WayneConrad even without solid lumps moving at speed, [sympathetic detonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_detonation) can be caused by shock alone, even in some compositions that won't cook off

Comment: The threat is sympathetic detonation, not the charge being hit by a material object hard enough to detonate it.